# Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 100"

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to hadoop programming and while trying reduce side join i got error Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 100". 
I have checked the input file are Ok .

My reducer Code is `

```
public void reduce (IntWritable key , Iterable<Text> value , Context context) throws IOException , InterruptedException{

    // value : TRAN\t product name \t Amt and CUST \t custometr name
    String data = new String();
    int amount=0;
    String name =null;
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    for (Text val : value){

        String[] line = val.toString().split("\t");
        if (line[0].equals(new String("TRANS").trim())){
            //data += line[1]+"\t";
            s.append(line[1]+"");
            amount+=Integer.parseInt(line[2]);
        }
        else if(line[0].equals(new String("CUST").trim())){

            name = line[1];


        }

        data= s.toString()+ Integer.toString(amount);
context.write(new Text(name), new Text(data));
```

and my two mapper are :

```
package reduceSideJoin.reducejoin;

public class transMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable ,Text , IntWritable , Text > {

public void map(LongWritable key , Text value , Context context) throws IOException , InterruptedException{

    String[] line = value.toString().split(",");
    String data = "TRANS"+ "\t" + line[1]+"\t " + line[3];
    context.write(new IntWritable (Integer.parseInt(line[0])), new Text(data) );

    }

}
```

and

```
package reduceSideJoin.reducejoin;

public class userMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, IntWritable, Text> {
public void map (LongWritable key, Text value , Context context) throws IOException , InterruptedException{

    String [] line = value.toString().split(",");
    String data = "CUST"+"\t"+line[1];
    context.write(new IntWritable (Integer.parseInt(line[0])), new Text(data));

    }

}
```

and my files are

Transaction data

```
0001,crax,2,300
0002,munch,1,10
0003,lays,1,20
0004,ship,1,200
0005,barOne,3,400
0002,crax,2,300
0001,kurkure,3,100
0003,milk,1,20
0004,butter,2,300
0005,meat,1,1220
0002,color,1,230
0003,dailrymilk,1,20
```

and customer data is

```
0001,Sunil Kumar , Mumbai,India
0002,Vikas mandal, Haryana, India
0003,Karan, JFK,France
0004,manish,banglore,India
0005,devesh,meerut,India
```

and i got error 16/05/30 00:23:00 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
16/05/30 00:23:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1464547777880_0001_r_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 100"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)

Can someone help me to resolve this

Thanks

Comment: There appears to be a spurious space in `" 100"`.

Comment: Use trim() function on your input string to remove whitespace example amount+=Integer.parseInt(line[2].trim());

Comment: I have changed my Reducer code to `amount+=Integer.parseInt(line[2].trim());`  but now it is showing nullpointer Exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NumberFormatException is because:

There is an extra blank space in the line below (just after the last "\t"):

```
String data = "TRANS"+ "\t" + line[1]+"\t " + line[3];
```

You should replace with:

```
String data = "TRANS"+ "\t" + line[1]+"\t" + line[3];
```

After that, you will still receive a NullPointerException in the line:

```
context.write(new Text(name), new Text(data));
```

That's because you are settng the variable `name` only in the "else" block.

You can solve this by setting the `name` this way:

```
if (line[0].equals(new String("TRANS").trim())){
    name = line[1]; // <==== here
    s.append(line[1]+"");
    amount+=Integer.parseInt(line[2]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel  , after watching the result i understand the problem